# How to access variable used when parsing JSON in another function?

Tags: swift, uikit, jsondecoder

I'm trying to use the text I get back from the API and put it in a UILabel but I can't figure out a way to put it in a global scope.

This is what the VC looks like (note I am new to swift):

```
import UIKit

class RandomVC: UIViewController {
    class randomData: Decodable {
          var text: String
    }
 
    var randomText = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        configureRandomText()
        
        let jsonUrlString = "https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let textData = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(randomData.self, from: data)
                print(textData.text)
                self.randomText.text = textData.text
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:" , jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func configureRandomText() {
        view.addSubview(randomText)
        randomText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        randomText.text = textData.text // <- Error here: Cannot find 'textData' in scope
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            randomText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            randomText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

The error is in the `configureRandomText` method above (see comment in the code).

Comment: Bellow  the `print(textData.text)` write `self.randomText.text = textData.text`

Comment: Please put *all* the relevant code into the question; don't just add an image of it.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis UILabel.text must be used from main thread only

Comment: Next mind fixed it, DispatchQueue.Main.async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have declare the variable `textData` at global scope like this

```
var textData : randomData?
```

and need to change some of the code while assigning the data to model and for the `configureRandomText()` method.

```
do {
  self.textData = try
  JSONDecoder().decode(randomData.self, from: data)
  print(textData?.text ?? "")
  configureRandomText()
} catch let jsonErr {
  print("Error serializing json:" , jsonErr)
}
```

```
func configureRandomText() {
    view.addSubview(self.randomText)
    self.randomText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.randomText.text = self.textData?.text ?? ""
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.randomText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        self.randomText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}
```